# Can I use a report paramater as a section of the WHERE clause

Tags: sql, t-sql, report, ssrs-2008

I have a query that runs great as is like this

```
WHERE (customer IN (@cust))
```

and @cust is a customer or a multiple list of customers

what I want to add is an `AND` with more in another optional parameter like

```
No: @expiring = " "
```

OR

```
Yes: @expiring = " AND getDate() >= dateAdd(d,[expiryWarning],[expiryDate]) "
```

then I want to add that to the end of the `WHERE` and have it do that second part if it's chosen from the dropdown as Yes or No so I can show the whole list of customers or just the ones expiring in the report.

```
WHERE (customer IN (@cust)) @expiring
```

but I am seeing an error when I try to run this report

that `there's an error near @expiring`

any insight? I've been searching all day, is this even possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change your where clause to take `@expiring` into account like this.

```
WHERE customer in (@cust)
    AND (@expiring='No' OR getDate() >= dateAdd(d,[expiryWarning],[expiryDate]))
```

So if @expring is 'No' then that part of the WHERE clause always returns true. If expiring = 'Yes' then the date criteria must be true else that part will return false.

Comment: Ahh ok I see what is going on, here, excellent thank you! I'll give it a try and mark yours as the answer --if-- WHEN it works.